# how to make jupyter notebook always focus on the latest output?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

when we execute a program in jupyter notebook and have lot of print, jupyter didn't auto scroll to the latest output. I have to scroll to know what is the latest output. how can I make it always showing the latest output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter notebook does not have the feature you want probably you will need to integrate some plugin. Search around the internet you will find what you want. Here one example check this repo:

https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

Comment: I found this from the link you gave
https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/scroll_down/readme.html

I haven't try it yet. but I think this is what I looking for. Thank you

Comment: Related option for those using JupyterLab [is described here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-have-new-printouts-at-top-of-cell/12683/2?u=fomightez). This ability doesn't require an extension in modern JupyterLab.